# Doh / dijit robot - no mouse actions happening

Tags: automated-tests, dojo, doh-robot

I wrote an automated test using dijit robot - but in order to be able to use relative paths within our web application, I created an OSGi service for our tests and put the test code in a velocity template.  When I try to run the tests, nothing happens.  If I use the same script in an html file and access it directly from windows explorer (not via localhost), it works fine.  I find that there are many cases that will make the dijit robot tests just not run - has anyone ran into this and found out all the little gotchas to make dijit tests run?

Comment: It seems to be working in IE now (sometimes not, but mostly yes) - but never in Firefox - does anyone know of any FF3-specific issues?

Answer (score 0):

Check out dijit.initRobot(), that might take care of some things for you.

One thing that was screwing up a lot of my tests is described [in this blog post](http://mindtrove.info/tidbit-dohrobot-initialization/) - basically the robot was not initializing because I was obscuring a special div that the robot clicks to initialize.

However I have realized that there are still quite a few problems with the doh robot - it just seems very fragile. Often I will have a working test, then add 1 robot command and the test will break. When I remove the line and try it again...well the robot wont run even though it is the exact same code as before.

I've found the best thing to do when writing robot code is to just clear the cache every time and cross your fingers. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Problem can be if you trying it with openjdk, run it on oracle java version